# Assign ID to control inside the grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

A grid view has 5 columns and more than 50 rows.
each row has a label with 4 controllers.
and I want to assign the ID for the 4 controllers from the data source, so I can use them later in code behind.
Is there any way to assign the ID automatically from the data source instead of create each row manually ?